# Usage Tracking in managed packages - can it be done and how?

Tags: managed-package, isv, analytics, usagemetrics

I want to use a form of [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) in my managed package where I show users different UI for the same feature randomly.

Since the [Salesforce Usage metrics feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2014/04/get-better-visibility-business-announcing-usage-metrics-pilot-feature.html) never left his quirky pilot there is no obvious solution to this. I thought of adding tracking tools like Google analytics to the Visualforce or Lightning pages but I fear this is more suitable for public websites that closed apps.

**Are you doing something similar or can you think of a pragmatic solution?**

Comment: Are you trying to track a `Visualforce` UI? Lightning? Standard?

Comment: Visualforce and Lightning UI. Will add that to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think a **`Hierarchy Custom Setting`** is well suited to the task at hand. You can add a variety of fields to track usage information, and you may need to be a bit creative, but it gives you a light object in which to store user specific data. Perfect!

A not very creatively named example of what I'm trying to get at:

```
public static void trackUsageA(/*some parameters*/)
{
    MyUsageSetting__c usage = MyUsageSetting__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
    if (usage.A_Count__c == 0)
        usage.A_Count__c = 1;
    else
        usage.A_Count__c += 1;
    upsert usage;
}
public static void trackUsageB(/*some parameters*/)
{
    MyUsageSetting__c usage = MyUsageSetting__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
    if (usage.B_Count__c == 0)
        usage.B_Count__c = 1;
    else
        usage.B_Count__c += 1;
    upsert usage;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get the data out of a customers private org back to the managed package vendor?

Comment: Callouts seem like the way to go there. Maybe set something up on Heroku or AWS...you could even plug the data into Google Sheets. At least using this strategy you could just call out on a daily basis with aggregate data instead of each time you want to track a feature.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Nice concept, but as pointed out I want to also need reporting over all users and orgs.